# Link a common Link to a particular Nav Item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm working on Project in React.js and facing a problem.
I have a sidebar containing different pages like; Payments, Domains, Hosting, etc. In all the pages, we've a common link "change domain". In my Payments page, we have a navbar containing different items such as Add Card, Add Address, etc. I want to load the Add Card nav-item once we click on "Change Domain" no matter what page we are on. It can be Payments, Domains, Hosting, or any other.
How I can achieve it? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I've tried passing props since we're not using Context API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.